# Squid prevents site load on pfSense

Tags: squid, pfsense

I've installed pfSense today, and it works fine and I'm very happy with it. However, when I enable Squid on pfSense, some webpages don't load and I get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error (whatismyipaddress.com doesn't work for example, but it does without Squid installed).. When I disable/remove the squid proxy server they work again.. What's causing this? The settings are almost default. On the 'GENERAL' tab I only enabled 'Allow users on interface' and 'Transparent proxy'. I also configured the local cache. It has 10GB disk space and the max size of a file to cache is 15MB.

It would be nice if someone could help me :)